# Copy object to other table - Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have two table:

```
First:
id | name  | password
 1 | peter | old

Second:
id | name  | password
```

I get object from table First:

```
$first = Doctrine::getTable('First')->find(1);

$copy = $first->copy();

$second = new Second($first);
$second->save();
```

or

```
$second = new Second($copy);
$second->save();
```

In both cases i have:

```
Second:
id | name  | password
 1 | NULL  | NULL 
 2 | NULL  | NULL
```

Is possible to make this copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with [`toArray`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Record.php#L1884) / [`fromArray`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Record.php#L1962) ?

```
$first = Doctrine::getTable('First')->find(1);

$second = new Second();
$second->fromArray($first->toArray());
$second->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you use clone? It's less cumbersome than using toArray, fromArray.

```
$first = Doctrine::getTable('First')->find(1);
//do whatever to $first here...

$second = clone $first;
$second->save();
```

You may have to set the ID field on $second to null though.

Comment: Wouldn't this just create a new record in the same table instead of copying the record to the 'Second' table?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but I don't think like this. Where did you see that? I don't think you can pass one entity as a parameter to the constructor of another.

Just do it manually or use reflection to copy all the fields:

```
$first = Doctrine::getTable('First')->find(1);

$second = new Second();
$second->setValue1($first->getValue1());
$second->setValue2($first->getValue2());
...
$second->save();
```

Comment: i know these solution, but i would like something faster ;)

Comment: this will be done in the end anyways, maybe not by you but by some code. or do you mean faster in terms of coding? that's why I said use reflection

Answer (score 0):

[From documentation](https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/A-Inside-the-Model-Layer-Propel#chapter_a_model_classes) peer classes are:

> classes that contain static methods to operate on the tables. They
> provide a way to retrieve records from the tables. Their methods
> usually return an object or a collection of objects of the related
> object class

and model classes represent a row in a table and exist for representing a row of table